# How to position kivy widgets in floatlayout using pos_hint?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm stuck trying to position widgets in kivy in a FloatLayout using pos_hint.
If the label exists from the beginning, e.g. if I can define the pos_hint in the .kv file, everything works as expected. However, I'm trying to create buttons later on. Using this .kv file (named layouttest.kv):

```
<NewButton@Button>:
    size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)

<BasicFloatLayout@FloatLayout>:
    Button:
        size_hint: (0.4, 0.2)
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.0, 'top': 1.0}
        text: 'create Button'
        on_release: self.parent.create_Button()
```

and this python code, I am trying to position newly created blank buttons at a random y-position ranging from 0%-100% of the size of my BasicFloatLayout, and at a random x-position ranging from 0-200px.
If I press the button once, everything behaves as expected. On a second press, the first created button will change its y-position such that it is identical with the newly created button. On a third press, both old buttons will align with the newly created button and so on. The x-positioning will however remain as expected. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong here?
(Bonus points if you can help me moving the buttons using the update function and pos_hint)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty 
from kivy.clock import Clock

import random

class BasicFloatLayout(FloatLayout):
    timer = NumericProperty(0)
    def update(self, *args):
        self.timer += 1
        for child in self.children:
            try: child.update()
            except AttributeError:
                pass
    def create_Button(self):
        button = NewButton( (random.random(), random.random()) )
        self.add_widget(button)
        
class NewButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, pos, **kwargs):
        super(NewButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.pos[0] = 200*pos[0]
        self.pos_hint['y'] = pos[1]

class layouttestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        GUI = BasicFloatLayout()
        Clock.schedule_interval(GUI.update, 1/30.)
        return GUI

if __name__ == "__main__":
    layouttestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make `pos_hint: {'x': 0.0, 'y': 0.5}`(because it's hard to get 2 different things work, if you are using x, use y instead of Top, if you are using Top, then use Bottom insead of x)

Second, instead of giving `on_release: self.parent.create_Button()` in the kv file, do this: `on_release: root.create_Button()`

Third, you have only assigned for the y value , you should also assign for the x value, the line is `self.pos_hint['y'] = pos[1]` inside the NewButton class.

But you can make it more simple by doing this:

```
#from your first class......
def create_Button(self):
        button = NewButton(self.pos_hint{'x' : random.random(), 'y' : random.random()}
        self.add_widget(button)

class NewButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, *kwargs):
        pass
```

Hope this makes some kind of sense, and you can modify it more.
(Note: I haven't wrote the begining part of your main class, I am lazy ;-p)

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work...
First, I agree, it would be easier to configure the two things independently, but doing that covers the real problem even more, because then all the buttons stack on top of each other and it looks like it is only one button moving. In fact, it is an increasing number of buttons stacked.
Second, I agree. However, it is only a cosmetic difference.
Third, this is somehow similar to first.

Your code example doesn't compile. If I call
button = NewButton(pos_hint={'x': random.random(), 'y': random.random()}) it does work, but it produces the same bug.

Comment: @fruchti then try removing the first button by using self.remove_widget(button) after adding the self.add_widget(button), to do this don't use the kv lang for this, use logical code here. And if possible try to give different names.

Comment: but I do not want to remove the first button, I want to create ten or twenty of them...

Comment: @fruchti if they still do not work then it is not possible for kivy, kivy.md might work, I love kivy but it has some drawbacks too, I was trying to create a chat app with kivy, I need to place new messages as labels, and just append the screen so that the user might scroll chats with the person. But such "scrollable label" type thing doesn't exist in kivy. You might try using a different gui framework, or use kivy.md!

Comment: I brought everything to kivy.md but it is the same thing there...
I fear I just don't understand how to initiate the buttons correctly. I'm setting the pos_hint for all instances of the class, not just for a single one. Except if I create it in a .kv file first, one that was created in .kv will stay at its expected pos_hint.
Anyways, thank you for the kivy.md recommendation